# WCF Service in iis 8 windows 8 Beta

Tags: wcf, windows-8, iis-8

We have a WCF Service running fine in IIS 7. We are migrating to Windows 8 server. We deployed the WCF Service in IIS 8. When browsing the SVC File getting the below Configuration Error

> There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined

Config Source section in the Error page

```
<sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
<section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
<sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when using config file meant for 2.0 in 4.0 app pool you can either delete all these sections from your web.config if you don't need it or change app pool to 2.0

Comment: And config can be also corrected if you have visual studio 2010.